# tooltip functions using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, tooltip

```
function showTooltip(elementId) {
    console.log('Showing tooltip for element:', elementId);
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(`tooltip-${elementId}`);
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
};
}

function hideTooltip(elementId) {
    console.log('Hiding tooltip for element:', elementId);
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(`tooltip-${elementId}`);
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
};

<div>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="login-username" name="username" onmouseover="showTooltip('login-username')" onmouseout="hideTooltip('login-username')">
    <div id="tooltip-login-username" class="tooltip">Your username for login.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your code - I guess you didn't check the browsers *developer* tools console for errors

Answer (score 0):

Added event listeners to the username input, which shows or hides a tooltip when the user hovers over it.

```js
function showTooltip(elementId) {
    console.log('Showing tooltip for element:', elementId);
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(`tooltip-${elementId}`);
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
};

function hideTooltip(elementId) {
    console.log('Hiding tooltip for element:', elementId);
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(`tooltip-${elementId}`);
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
};

const usernameInput = document.getElementById('login-username');
usernameInput.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    showTooltip('login-username');
});

usernameInput.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    hideTooltip('login-username');
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="login-username" name="username">
  <div id="tooltip-login-username" class="tooltip">Your username for login. </div>
</div>
```